# reproduce successfull curl request in Arduino ESP8266

Tags: curl, arduino, esp8266

I am a noob with the ESP8266 and Arduino IDE/code.

I have a IR sensor connected to an ESP-07 and have code that successfully turns on an LED when motion is detected.

I am trying to send a POST request to a raspberry pi running Webiopi to turn on a relay that is connected to the RPi.

I have successfully run a curl request on the RPi which turns on GPIO pin #11 and activates the relay tied to that pin:
`curl -v -X POST -u username:password http://192.168.2.10:8000/GPIO/11/value/0`

Server response is:

```
    * About to connect() to 192.168.2.10 port 8000 (#0)
    *   Trying 192.168.2.10...
    * connected
    * Connected to 192.168.2.10 (192.168.2.10) port 8000 (#0)
    * Server auth using Basic with user 'webiopi'
    > POST /GPIO/11/value/1 HTTP/1.1
    > Authorization: Basic **a key was provided by the server**
    > User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
    > Host: 192.168.2.201:8000
    > Accept: */
    > 
    * additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
    * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
    < HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    < Server: WebIOPi/0.7.1/Python3.2
    < Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 01:27:05 GMT
    < Cache-Control: no-cache
    < Content-Type: text/plain
    < Content-Length: 1
    < 
    * Closing connection #0
```

I need to replicate this curl request on my ESP-07 using Arduino code.

I have tried this code, but the relay doesn't turn on and no output from the Serial Monitor window comes through when the POST is submitted.

```
char server[] = "192.168.2.10"
if (client.connect(server, 8000)) {
  Serial.println("Connected to server");
  // Make a HTTP request
  client.println("Authorization: Basic **I put the key generated from the curl call here**");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  client.println("Content-Length: 35");
  client.println("username=username&password=password");
  client.println("User-Agent: curl/7.26.0");
  client.println("Host: 192.168.2.10:8000");
  client.println("POST /GPIO/11/value/0 HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Accept: */*");
  client.println();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("disconnecting");
  Serial.println("==============");
  Serial.println();
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    }
  client.stop(); //stop client
  }
```

My apologies in advance if this request is too cryptic, but this is my first time posting on such a forum.

Many thanks in advance...:-)

@Cagdas, @Defozo, thx for your responses...
This is what tried, but the code did not turn on the LED.

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://192.168.2.10:8000/");
http.addHeader("User-Agent", "curl/7.26.0"); 
http.setAuthorization("username", "password");
auto httpCode = http.POST("/GPIO/11/value/0");
http.end();
```

@cagdas So I tried this next, still LED does not turn on

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://192.168.2.10:8000/");
http.addHeader("User-Agent", "curl/7.26.0"); 
http.POST("username=username&password=password");
http.POST("/GPIO/11/value/0");
http.end();
```

and just to reiterate, this was the curl call I was trying to replicate:

```
curl -v -X POST -u username:password http://192.168.2.10:8000/GPIO/11/value/0
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use HTTP client of Esp8266 for the sake of leanness.

```
HTTPClient http; 
http.begin("192.168.2.10:8000/");
http.addHeader("User-Agent: curl/7.26.0"); http.POST("username=username&password=password");
http.end();
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use `setAuthorization` method as well/instead.

Comment: Of course, that is possible @Defozo. Marked you up.